# Can't Seem to See Custom Telemetry in App Insights

Tags: c#, botframework

I tried adding custom telemetry per the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

I am missing something because I cannot find my custom event in the App Insights logs.

I tried interacting with the bot and searching the App Insights logs for "VeryImportantProperty" and "VeryImportantValue"

I wrote this class:

```
public class TelemetryMiddleware : TelemetryLoggerMiddleware
{

    public TelemetryMiddleware(IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient, bool logPersonalInformation)
        : base(telemetryClient, logPersonalInformation)
    {

    }
    protected override async Task OnReceiveActivityAsync(Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertyItems = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"VeryImportantProperty", "VeryImportantValue" }
        };

        var properties = await FillReceiveEventPropertiesAsync(activity, propertyItems);

        TelemetryClient.TrackEvent(TelemetryLoggerConstants.BotMsgReceiveEvent, properties);
    }
}
```

I added it in startup.cs as a service available for injection:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMiddleware, TelemetryMiddleware>();
```

I also added all the other items named in the article required as injectable services.

I deployed the bot and interacted with it, but I cannot find my VeryImportantValue or property even after a full search of my App Insights logs.

I’m sure I am missing something, but from the docs, I cannot determine what it is.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see these events by going to `Azure Portal > All Resources > Application Insights Resource > Overview page > Logs (Analytics)` which is along the top, above the details for the Application Insights resource.

Then if you enter the following for your query:

```
customEvents
| where name == "BotMessageReceived"
```

and click run (you may have to select the query text you entered before clicking run.

Your `VeryImportantProperty` data should show under the `customDimensions` column.

The getting started information is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/analytics).

**Edit**

If you still cannot see the log entries then you will need to debug where the issue is. The steps I would recommend are:

1. Get the latest version of the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases).
2. Update your `TelemetryMiddleware` class to have a the following field `private IBotTelemetryClient _telemetryClient;`
3. Update your `TelemetryMiddleware` constructor to assign the value from the `telemetryClient` parameter to your new `_telemetryClient` field.
4. Update the call inside `OnReceiveActivityAsync` to use the new `_telemetryClient` field instead of the `TelemetryClient` class (you are calling `TrackEvent` statically currently which isn't what you want.
5. [Run your bot locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) using the Bot Framework Emulator.
6. Add a breakpoint on the line where you call `TrackEvent`
7. Create the scenario which should trigger `OnReceiveActivityAsync` (send a message to the bot).
8. Use `F10` to step over the `TrackEvent` line and ensure that it is called successfully.
9. At this stage I would also [inspect your variables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/) to ensure they have the values that you expect.
10. Wait for the event to flow through to App Insights (might take up to 5 minutes).
11. If this still does not work I would [create a new Application Insights API key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-app-insights-keys?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#api-key) and updating the following places with the new value:

    - For local testing:
    - Your appsettings.json file so that you can test locally.
    - For production:
    - The `Application Insights Instrumentation key` under the `Settings` tab of your Web App Bot in Azure.
    - Also check that the value for `Application Insights Application Id` under the `Settings` tab of your Web App Bot in Azure matches the `Application Id` value under the `API Access` tab of your Application Insights resource.
12. Follow the steps above to test locally using the emulator.
13. Once the logs are flowing through locally use the [Test in Web Chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#test-the-bot-1) functionality to ensure that it is working in production.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't -- that is the problem I'm struggling with here.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some debugging steps that you can take.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, none of my custom properties or events show in AppInsights unless i'm in developer mode using the emulator. When the Bot is in MS Teams none of that stuff shows in AppInsights...

Comment: @J_L please open a new question. I would suggest the first thing to look at would be to see if ANY telemetry is going through to Application Insights, then proceed accordingly with your investigation.

Comment: @MattStannett, apologies, after that comment I noticed when in MS Teams the data shows in the application's AppInsights instance instead of the QnA Maker instance. That's strange to me, but it gets me the data I need.